# I have million rows in one table. I am tolde to use union instead on in clause for performance reason. is it true?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-performance

We have million rows in one table.

our select:

```
select * from tableA where column1 in ("a", "b", "c", "d") and where column2 = "abc";
```

and we have unique index on column1 and column2 combined.

I was told to swtich to :

```
select * from tableA where column1 = "a" and column2 = "abc"
union
select * from tableA where column1 = "b" and column2 = "abc"
union
select * from tableA where column1 = "c" and column2 = "abc"
union
select * from tableA where column1 = "d" and column2 = "abc";
```

We could have from 1 to 100 different values in IN clause. So is it better to run one statement with IN clause or run 100 statement and perform union.

Comment: If you already have the table, you can easily measure the difference between the two queries yourself, can you not?

Comment: I would use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` so as to tax the database a little less.

Comment: usually run partial in a big job one by one, is  faster than  just run a whole thing.

Comment: With a proper index on tableA (column2,column1), the `in` query should be more efficient -- if the optimizer doesn't treat them as exactly equivalent, that is. But one million rows really isn't very much.

Comment: Your syntax is off.  Oracle doesn't use double quotes for strings.  And `and where` is not proper SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique index on `column1, column2` -- in that order -- then the version with `union` will definitely take advantage of the index.  As mentioned in a comment, you should use `union all` rather than `union`.  This eliminates the step of removing duplicates (even if there are none).  This would be a handful of index lookup operations and should go quite fast.

Whether Oracle uses an index as desired for the first version is somewhat open:

```
where column1 in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') and column2 = 'abc'
```

Most database would *not* use an index optimally in this case.  If a database used the index, it would use the index for `column1` lookups and then scan the index comparing values to `column2`.  Oracle might have some additional smarts that will use an index effectively here.

However, it is easy to fix things.  If you have an index on `column2, column1`, then that index would be used for the `where` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Who told you to switch?  Did they provide some evidence that the second approach is actually more efficient in your environment with your data?

Unless your statistics are woefully incorrect or there is way more going on, I would find it very unlikely that the `UNION` approach would be more efficient than an `IN`.  If you were going to break up the query, using `UNION ALL` would be more efficient than using `UNION` because it wouldn't force extra sorts to check for and eliminate (non-existent) duplicate rows.  Assuming a relatively recent version of Oracle, I would expect the optimizer to be able to internally rewrite the `UNION ALL` query as an `IN`.

Given that you have the table in question, though, you should be able to evaluate the actual performance of the two options in your actual environment.  You should be able to see whether one approach consistently outperforms the other, whether one does less logical I/O than the other, etc.  You should also be able to determine whether the two queries actually generate different plans.  If the `UNION ALL` approach is more efficient, I'd strongly consider looking at the statistics that have been gathered on your table and index(es) to determine why the optimizer isn't finding the more efficient plan with the `IN` statement.

Comment: thanks for reply. it was suggested by our dba. I will followup with him with steps you suggested. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another alternative, the statement could be written as:

```
select * from tableA where (column1 = "a" and column2 = "abc")
or (column1 = "b" and column2 = "abc") 
or (column1 = "c" and column2 = "abc") 
or (column1 = "d" and column2 = "abc") ;
```